# How to map an int to a boolean mvc core2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, type-conversion, automapper

I'm using MVC Core 2.1 and AutoMapper 5.0.1.

I want to convert Viewmodel property from `short` to `bool` but it doesn't convert.

How to solve this problem?

```
CreateMap<AccessResultSp, AccessResultViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ShowAccess,
               opts => opts.MapFrom((src =>Tobool(src.ShowAccess)))
              )
    .ReverseMap()

public class AccessResultViewModel
{
    public bool? ShowAccess { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hey @saeed3164, please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html

Comment: What is the logic to convert `short` to `bool` which are two different data types? What is the current value from ViewModel and what is your expected value for Db.